# Is Gravity on a bell curve?

Tags: gravity, space, distance

Is there a point where gravity decreases the farther away from an object that is not related to distance?

Comment: Could you perhaps rephrase the question? It is difficult to understand precisely what you are asking.

Comment: Hi Jen. Can you clarify what you are asking? It has been suggested that at very large distances the gravitational force might depart from the Newtonian law - [MOND is an example of this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Newtonian_dynamics). However the departure from Newtonian behaviour is small.

Comment: I was actually looking for exactly what you asked about, don't know why this was closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables "on a bell curve", if I am interpreting you correctly, are random variables with probability distributions, that is, they are non-deterministic. Repeated measurements (or experiments) of random variables yield distinct results, with probability obeying a certain cumulative distribution function (CDF). One such distribution is the famous [bell curve](http://news.mit.edu/sites/mit.edu.newsoffice/files/images/2012/20120208160239-1_0.jpg) (shown are the chances of falling in certain intervals).

I guess your question can be rephrased as "Is Gravity non-deterministic?" -- that is, would we expect different results from repeated measurements of Gravity at the same distance from an attractive object?

The answer would be **no**, because the force of gravity is theoretically **consistent across measurements**. In contrast, Quantum Mechanics ellucidates phenomena at very small scales that indeed effectively *do not* yield the same results for repeated measurements.

Keep in mind that gravity measurement *instruments*, however, do measure "on a bell curve", because of error. The source of error is usually noise: a plethora a small interference effects (ranging from radio waves, vibrations, to thermal fluctuation of electronics).

If you get a chronometer and measure the height $h$ a ball released at time $t=0$ has fallen at time $t=1s$, you might expect from the effects of gravity alone the ball has fallen $g/2$ meters, giving a measurement of your local gravity $g$. However, in practice you won't obtain consistent results (that's an easy experiment to try yourself! you can do it by using smartphone video recoding and dropping objects against a measurement tape; you should get $g/2 \approx 4.9$).

Comment: Please don't answer unclear questions with wild guesses as to what they might mean.

Comment: @ACuriousMind he nailed it.